# Allow CrossContext in WebSphere

Tags: java, servlets, websphere-7, cross-context

I need to dispatch a request from one application to another by using `sc.getRequestDispatcher("/Forward2.jsp");` and this won't work if the web-server isn't properly configured. I found that in Tomcat we can configure it using `crossContext="true"`. But where can I configure WebSphere 7 to achieve the same results?

Thanks.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @DaveS no, I used JavaScript and HTML form to achieve it